# deleting rows in sqlyog having null values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a table which dosen't have any key(foreign key and...). 
Some of table fields have null value.
when I use the command:

```
DELETE FROM `woe300websnt` WHERE (Arg1=NULL AND Rel=NULL  AND Arg2=NULL);
```

the query is run successfully but when I use

```
select * from woe300websnt
```

I see that no change is applied and these rows are remained. what is wrong with me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` is not a value - it's the absence of a value. You cannot use the `=` operator on it, you need to use the `is` operator instead:

```
DELETE FROM woe300websnt 
WHERE Arg1 IS NULL AND Rel IS NULL AND Arg2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, and I have another question:
when we use java to delete from table we have syntax like this:


 String query = "delete from users where id = ?";

      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

      preparedStmt.setInt(1, 3);

what about this case?

Comment: @VahidehTabrizi If you have another question, please post it as a new question. Thanks!